# Reading characters to create picture

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

Basically an input file contains lines of integers indicating a number of spaces and, alternately, characters to be printed to create a picture. The first integer on a line will always be a number of spaces to print(this may be 0). Every alternate integer will be a number of characters to print. The last integer on a line will always be -1, flagging the end of the line. For example, the line 0 2 4 2 -1, would represent "0 spaces - 2 characters - 4 spaces - 2 characters - next line." The characters can be anything such as "#" or "%"

here is my idea of a loop

```
while there is more of the file to read
{
    set your boolean flag for spaces to true (you'll toggle it back and forth)
    read the first number
    while the number just read is not -1
    {
        if the flag is true print that number of spaces and toggle the flag
        else print that number of characters and toggle the flag
        read the next number
    }
    print a newline
}
```

What I need is how to read the line and print the correct spaces/characters. I cant figure out the best way to read each character considering each line has varying lengths and spaces.
Here is an input.txt file example.

```
4 3 3 -1
2 4 1 1 2 -1
1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 -1
0 3 2 1 1 3 -1
5 1 4 -1
2 3 1 3 1 -1
1 5 1 3 -1
1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1
1 5 1 3 -1
2 3 1 3 1 -1
```

I was planning on using

```
String.format("%" + numberOfSpaces + "s", "");
```

to print the spaces and characters.

Comment: Check out [`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.repeat()`](http://tinyurl.com/ljb6ude)

Comment: If everything in the file is an integer, then use [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) and [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()).